# Difference between containsObject: and member: methods of NSSet?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, foundation

What is the diference between these two methods belonging to the NSSet class:

```
-(BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
-(id)member:(id)object
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer lies in the return values. containsObject returns a YES or a NO depending on if the object you send belongs to that particular set.

member returns id, which means that it returns the actual object if that object is part of the set.

As an example, you have an NSSet, aSet, with anObject. anObject belongs to the set.

```
[aSet containsObject:anObject]; //returns YES
[aSet member:anObject]; //If the set contains an object equal to object (as determined by isEqual:) then that object (typically this will be object), otherwise nil.
```

If anObject does not exist in aSet:

```
[aSet containsObject:anObject]; //return NO
[aSet member:anObject]; //return nil
```

Comment: I'd bet that the return value of `member:` might *not* be `anObject`.  That is, if the set contains an object that `isEqual:` to the argument, the set's object will be returned.

Comment: @bbum - yes, that is definitely the case. I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: But think the real question here is whether or not containsObject: also uses isEqual: to determine the result, or is it uses isIdenticalToObject:.

Comment: @AvrahamShukron containsObject in fact uses isEqual: if the underlying class has implemented it.